# How to access a disabled button

Tags: javascript

An html button in the form is disabled on the fly using

```
document.getElementById('Btn').disabled = true;
```

Later, I wish to know the status of the button, if disabled or enabled. Using the following doesn't work:

```
if (document.getElementById('Btn').disabled == "true") {
```

What is the solution?

Comment: `document.getElementById('Btn').hasAttribute('disabled')` should be sufficient.

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('Btn').disabled) {` as `disabled` is already a boolean (holding either `true` or `false`).

Comment: Don't put quotes around `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
if (document.getElementById('Btn').disabled) {
```

Browser will render `disabled="disabled"` or just `disabled`. It's dependent on browser implementation. Thus, just checking `true` string with disabled attribute will not work.

The preceding code will just check if it has disabled attribute or say disabled attribute is available there.

Comment: Browser that behave according to the standard will return a boolean for `document.getElementById('Btn').disabled`. That's why the test `document.getElementById('Btn').disabled == "true"`  fails because it would be `true=="true"`.

Comment: @t.niese yes, that's what it implies. You should be reading my statement carefully: just checking **true string**...

Comment: What I meant, is that it is not relevant if the browser uses one of the standard conform ways `disabled="disabled"`, `disabled=""` or `disabled` to represent the disbaled state for the attribute. The importatnt part is that the type of the property `disabled` will always be a boolean, no matter how the browser does represent it as attribute.

Comment: ...and last sentence verifies that.

Answer (score 1):

The `disabled` property accessor can be quite confusing. There is both an attribute and a property accessor which shadows the attribute.

You can use `document.getElementById('Btn').hasAttribute('disabled')` to check whether the element is disabled, or simply `document.getElementById('Btn').disabled`, since the property getter returns a boolean as well:

```js
function logAttribute (btn, attr) {
  console.log(`hasAttribute ${btn.hasAttribute(attr)}`)
  console.log(`getAttribute ${btn.getAttribute(attr)}`)
  console.log(`hasOwnProperty ${btn.hasOwnProperty(attr)}`)
  console.log(`[attr] ${btn[attr]}`)
}

const btn = document.createElement('button')

console.log('----- uninitialized')
logAttribute(btn, 'disabled')
btn.disabled = true
console.log('----- set')
logAttribute(btn, 'disabled')
btn.disabled = false
console.log('----- unset')
logAttribute(btn, 'disabled')
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `disabled`  holds a boolean and not a string, so it has to be:

```
if (document.getElementById('Btn').disabled == true) {
```

Or just

```
if (document.getElementById('Btn').disabled) {
```

[w3c html5: 4.10.7 The input element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html#the-input-element):

```
interface HTMLInputElement : HTMLElement {
   // ... 
   attribute boolean disabled;
}
```

So no matter what value was et to the attribute or to the property,you will always get a boolean if you access the the property `disabled`.

Comment: @pushkin `true=="true"`  is `false` not true

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the `document.getElementById('Btn').disabled`  does access the proeprty, `document.getElementById('Btn').getAttribute('disabled')` returns the attribute, the attribute is a string, the property in this case is a boolean.